# Run bash script from Python but get Windows Error 193

Tags: python, shell, call, windowserror

I try to run shell script from Python, but instead I get

```
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

My simplified code is following:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["%s/scripts/test.sh"%work_path, "arg1", "arg2"])
```

Weird is that this works smoothly on Linux.

`test.sh` has valid path to bash in header and bash executable is included in `%PATH%`. I even tried to use parameter `shell=True`, but result is the same.

Comment: Does the script runs normally in CMD.exe or powershell ? How do you expect a shell script (sh,ksh,bash) to be able to run in Windows ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that, there is MinGW installed on windows machine.

Comment: I have never used MinGW , but i guess you need to call the shell  (bash i guess)  executable along with script.

Comment: The error message looks like you have a batch file intercepting you somewhere along the way.  Can you verify that `work_path` contains the path you intended, and if not, find out what messes it up?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  Here is the way I got things going to run a shell script from python in MinGW (msysgit):

```
from subprocess import call
arg1 = 1
arg2 = 10
cmd = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe', '-c', '~/bin/myscript', arg1, arg2]
result_code = call(cmd)
```

The key is to explicitly spell out the path to bash.exe as the first argument, '-c' (command) for the second and use the script as the third argument.  Subsequent arguments go to the script (sometimes -- see below).

Some caveats:

`%PROGRAMFILES%` and other windows variables do not resolve when searching for the bash.exe file -- you could probably get around this by using python to construct the path rather than hard coding the name.

Substitution of ~ for your mingw home directory works and the PATH variable from `.bashrc` or `.profile` works.  If you leave out the '-c' argument you can get to local scripts (in ~), but the mingw root file structure is not present for commands like "true" and "ls".

I haven't quite figured out when to have arguments combined and when not to have them combined for instance, this command works:

`cmd = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe', '-c', 'echo hi']
result_code = call(cmd)`

but this doesn't:

`cmd = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe', '-c', 'echo', 'hi']
result_code = call(cmd)`

However, with my shell script, this works:

`cmd = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe', '-c', '~bin/myscript', arg1, arg2]
result_code = call(cmd)`

but this doesn't:

`cmd = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe', '-c', '~bin/myscript 1 10']
result_code = call(cmd)`

In all cases result_code is 0 for the successful execution of bash.exe.  I do not know how to get output from the script back to python.  This prints output but does not send it back to the main process.  I need to get the result back to the calling program, but that is probably a whole other question involving output piping and file redirection.

In short.  It is a complete mess, but the script executes.  Surely there is a more consistent technique out there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The following works well for me:

```
import platform, os, subprocess

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    programfiles = ('PROGRAMW6432' if platform.architecture()[0] == '32bit'
                    else 'PROGRAMFILES')
    bash_exe = os.getenv(programfiles) + r'\Git\bin\bash'
    subprocess.call([bash_exe, '-c', 'echo hello'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a space in `bash.exe` path, invoking bash using subprocess won't work. A shortcut to address this problem is adding `bash.exe` on your *Path* environment variable. After this, you may execute the bash script as follows.

```
import subprocess

command = ['bash.exe', shell_script]
return_code = subprocess.call(command)
print('return code:' + str(return_code))
```